# Python : Did we just cross midnight

Tags: python, time

I have a little script that runs all the time in background. Every time we cross midnight I want to do something. The script uses the sleep function so it is not really sure if it is awake at 00:00:00 time. So I was thinking to have code like this:

```
last_time= time.now()
while True:
    if last_time < midnight && midnight < time.now():
        # do stuff
        last_time= time.now()
    sleep(some time)
```

But I didn't know how to code the proper line in the if statement.

Comment: Why not just use a cron job?

Comment: In Python the logical and is `and` instead of `&&`.

Comment: I had the same question :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `datetime` module to get the current local time as a `datetime` object. Its convenient because that object includes the day. Just check when that changes.

```
import datetime
import time

last_day = datetime.datetime.now().day
while True:
    day = datetime.datetime.now().day
    if day != last_day:
        last_day = day
        do_your_work()
    time.sleep(some_time)
```

Answer (score 1):

So last time I did this kind of thing I tried to keep things timezone specific and that helped me a lot so here is what I'd try and do. Note that I've used the pytz library here, so you will have to pip install that. Then also you might want to change the timezone to what you need.

```
from datetime import datetime, time
from time import sleep
import pytz


def get_times():
    my_timezone = pytz.timezone('America/Los_Angeles')
    last_time = my_timezone.normalize(datetime.now(tz=my_timezone))
    midnight = my_timezone.localize(datetime.combine(last_time.date(), time.max))
    return last_time, midnight


def main():
    last_time, midnight = get_times()

    while True:
        if last_time > midnight:
            # It's passed midnight we need to run it
            # do work here...
            # now we need to update midnight to todays midnight
            last_time, midnight = get_times()
        else:
            # we shouldn't run the work just update last time
            last_time, _ = get_times()
        sleep(10)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you purely have the clock time (by which I mean just the hour/minute/second of the day), one way to check this is to see if the new time is less than the old time: every other clock time is less than 23:59:59, for example.

Of course, time handling is messy and horrible and fraught with exceptions - most notably, what if we just fell back in an autumn clock change?

A more robust solution might be to see if we have changed dates: I can think of no examples where you pass midnight without the date changing.