# How to check if midnight has just passed?

Tags: python, python-3.x, raspberry-pi4

I need a function returning a boolean indicating if midnight has just passed.
I came up with this but I am not happy with the "form". Can anyone think of anything better? as in terms of efficiency/elegance?

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
   
def passed_midnight(delta=1):
    time_now = datetime.today   # see other comment below
    time_ago = time_now() - timedelta(minutes=delta)
    # next line with a dummy delta (zero) cuz "datetime.today - timedelta(days=1)" gives an error
    today = time_now() - timedelta(days=0)
    return today.strftime("%Y%m%d") != time_ago.strftime("%Y%m%d")

>>> print(passed_midnight, 10)
```

Comment: If you don't have any ***issues*** with this code, sounds more like it should go in [codereview.se]...

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it belongs in [codereview.se]

Comment: datetime.today is a function. You cannot use it like `datetime.today - timedelte(days=XX)`, you have to call the function like `datetime.today() - timedelta(days=XX)`

Comment: Here is a nice solution to this as it seems common problem https://stackoverflow.com/a/43432964/281545

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `datetime.today - timedelta(days=1)` gives an error because `datetime.today` is a function that needs to be called. This is why you must have felt the need to write `time_now()` with parentheses: it's calling the function, twice (with different results, because time has a tendency to pass).
- Avoid `strftime` in favour of [`date()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.date), which returns the date part only (as a `datetime.date` object).
- Use `datetime.now()` instead of `datetime.today()` so that subtracting a `timedelta` can take the timezone (and hence daylight savings time changeovers) into account.

So then you get this:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
   
def passed_midnight(delta=1):
    time_now = datetime.now()
    time_ago = time_now - timedelta(minutes=delta)
    return time_now.date() != time_ago.date()
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably misunderstood how to declare a function and how to call it.
Here is a version that fixed the issues with function calls:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

def passed_midnight(delta=1):
    today = datetime.today()
    time_ago = today - timedelta(minutes=delta)
    return today.strftime("%Y%m%d") != time_ago.strftime("%Y%m%d")

>>> print(passed_midnight(10))
False
```

Be careful, this code doesn't take care of time zones. The behavior will be different from a location to another